# Toggling border color on JLabel with mouseListener

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm making FreeCell for a project and I've made the cards as Icons for JLabels. I want to highlight a card by putting a border on it when it's clicked and then when it's clicked again or moved, I want the border to disappear.

```
mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseClicked(e);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2);
        JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
        label.setBorder(border);
    }
};
```

Comment: try calling label.revalidate()

Comment: It already creates the border when I click the card, I want the label to not have a border when I click the card a second time, or when a group of cards are moved